# How to timestamp with jQuery based off user's selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to produced a timestamp based off user's selection.

I have a form with an input value that will be empty:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sub_enddate" value=" " />
```

I need to have the empty value filled in with a time stamp based a certain value of time in the future off a user's selection:

```
<select name="Membership Duration">
<option value="">Select A Membership Duration</option>
<option class="6" value="6 Months">6 Month Membership</option>
<option class="3" value="3 Months">3 Month Membership</option>
<option class="1" value="1 Months">1 Month Membership</option>
</select>
```

The format will be the following: 20110325 (2011-03-25).  So if the user chooses from the drop down menu:

- "6 Month Membership" the value in the hidden input field will be: 20110925 (6 months in the future from today, March 25th, 2011).
- "3 Month Membership" the value in the hidden input field will be: 20110625 (3 months in the future from today, March 25th, 2011).
- "1 Month Membership" the value in the hidden input field will be: 20110425 (1 month in the future from today, March 25th, 2011).

Comment: `(new Date).setMonth((new Date).getMonth() + 6)` will return the timestamp of 6 months in the future from now.  You could then format it to your format wishes.

Comment: hey pimvdb, thnx so much for your reply.  i sort of understand what you're saying, but a bit clueless on actually implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**See example of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/T8AcD/)

This oughtta do the trick:

```
$('#mem_dur').change(function(e) {
    var tVal = $(this).find('option:selected').val()[0],
        tDate = new Date(),
        mDate, mDateMS, mDateStr
        oneMonth = 31 * 86400000;

    mDateMS = tDate.getTime() + tVal * oneMonth;
    mDate = new Date(mDateMS);
    mDateStr = String(mDate.getFullYear()) + 
               ((mDate.getMonth() < 9) ? "0" + (mDate.getMonth() + 1) : mDate.getMonth() + 1) + 
               ((mDate.getDate() < 10) ? "0" + mDate.getDate() : mDate.getDate());

    mDateStr = (isNaN(parseInt(mDateStr,10))) ? "" : mDateStr;

    $('#sub_enddate').val(mDateStr);
});
```

Comment: this does work...thnx!  the only question i have for you: on 6 months out, it adds +2 the day of the month (i.e. today is the 25th and it outputs 27), for 3 months out, it adds +1 to the day of the month (i.e. today is the 25th and it outputs 26).  Any idea why?  Ideally I'd like to keep it to the same day (i.e. in this case 25) based off today's date.

Comment: Mine converts months to miliseconds and treats all months as being 31 days (hence the extra days).  I would use one of the solutions that uses `setMonth()` if you don't want to give your members a little bonus of a few free days.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/C2tW8/1/).

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var months = $(this).val().replace(' Months', '')*1,
        today = new Date(),
        expiration = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + months)),
        month = expiration.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' + (expiration.getMonth() + 1) : (expiration.getMonth() +1) + '',
        date = expiration.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + expiration.getDate() : expiration.getDate() + '',
        formatted = expiration.getFullYear() + month + date;

    $('input[name="sub_enddate"]').val(formatted);
});
```

Comment: You need `expiration.getMonth() < 9` since you're adding 1 to the value.  Otherwise, nice job!

Comment: hmmm...this one puts "NaNNaNNaN" in the value for the input field...not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the `setMonth` and `getMonth` functions are most important.

I made this up: http://jsfiddle.net/TrsNX/1/.

```
Number.prototype.fillUpWithZeroes = function() {
    // function to make a number like 3 formatted to 03.
    return (this + "").length === 1 ? "0" + this : "" + this;
}

$('select').change(function() {
    var time_now = new Date; // current time
    var chosen_value = $(this).val(); // chosen amount of months
    var time_in_future = new Date( // construct future time using value
                          time_now.setMonth(
                           time_now.getMonth()
                           + (chosen_value-0)
                          )
                         );

    var year = time_in_future.getFullYear(); // format everything
    var month = (time_in_future.getMonth() + 1).fillUpWithZeroes();
                 // Month starts at 0 (January)! So add 1.
    var date = time_in_future.getDate().fillUpWithZeroes();
    var formatted = year + month + date;

    $('input').val(formatted);
});
```